# Sharepoint 2010 - Create a custom menu

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

Does anybody knows a good step by step tutorial to create a custom menu like the standard QuickLaunchMenu (SharePoint:AspMenu) or a good tutorial to modify the existing QuickLaunchMenu? 
I'd like to add a background image attribute to the sitemap. This image should be rendered in every menu item. I have no idea how to create a costum menu.

Any help would be appreciated.

thx

Answer (score 2):

No need to use a custom menu. I suggest you use CSS to add your image to every navigation item.

Comment: every link or rather li has a special image so I can't do it with CSS.

Comment: yes you can do this with CSS, you can overload the existing class and assign your own background image. When you add your css to your page markup you can add the after attribute - http://blog.drisgill.com/2009/11/sp2010-branding-tip-3-getting-your-css.html

Comment: but how? The element with the name "sport" should have a blue image, the element with the name "team" should have a blue image. It should be completely dynamic.

Comment: Then I suggest jQuery + CSS. Apply different classes dynamically with jQuery depending on the name.

Comment: good idea. thx! But on my navigation there are menu item which aren't pages like "Libraries" or "Discussions". I would like to have a menu based on pages (like if you click on "Site pages"). How can pages be hierarchical?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good way to customize the menu however you want. It pulls the data from the sharepoint navigation and still allows custom navigation without too much coding.
http://sharepoint2010customnavigation.blogspot.com/